# How to instantiate my variable in another file

Tags: python, flask, oauth

Hello everyone I'm trying to do something very simple but all the documentation out do this on the same file.

I want to use oauth in my flask app and this is my main.py file

```
from flask import Flask
from login_routes import login
from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth

app = Flask(__name__)
oauth = OAuth(app)

app.register_blueprint(login)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

And my login_routes.py has these lines

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, url_for, redirect, session
from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth
import settings


# OAuth config
google =  oauth.register(
    name='google',
    client_id=settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    access_token_url=settings.GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI,
    access_token_params=None,
    authorize_url=settings.GOOGLE_AUTH_URI,
    authorize_params=None,
    api_base_url='https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/',
    client_kwargs={'scope': 'openid profile email'}
)
```

However oauth is not declared in my login_routes.py, I dont know how to bring that variable from main instance to this other file, I tried importing main.py which on my brain makes no sense because that ends up on a circular reference error please let me know how to instantiate this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

In main.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
oauth = OAuth(app)

# assign your oauth to a variable (property) of app instance
app.OAUTH = oauth
```

In login_routes.py

```
# This pulls in the app object
from flask import Blueprint, current_app as app

# Since you're registering 'login' as a blueprint in main.py, define it here
login = Blueprint('login', __name__)

# you can do access the oauth instance as app.OAUTH e.g
abc = app.OAUTH....
```

Comment: What is ```current_app``` it's undefined, I don't get what should be over there, probably you mean ```from flask import current_app as app``` , however that gives me an error ```This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the documentation for more information.```

Comment: Yes, that was a typo - it should be ```from flask import current_app as app```.  Define ```login``` as a Blueprint - see my updated answer

Comment: This is not working :(  , if I declare routes and oauth inside main.py everything works as expected but when I try to break it down in blueprints I can't get to instantiate ```oauth = Oauth(app)``` in my blueprint, this is terrible because it breaks the whole purpose of using blueprints...

Comment: you should know  - if you go with my suggestion, then it means you have to do ```google =  app.OAUTH.register(....```

Comment: Yes I tried that and it gives me the error I mentioned above ```This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the documentation for more information.```